# How to create an HTMLTable in C# 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows 7 64-bit/Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, html-table

I trying to create a new table in C#.NET 2010 so that i can return the table in a parameter. The usual way to create the object is to do:

```
mshtml.HTMLTable objTable = new mshtml.HTMLTable();
```

But this errors out in the debugger with:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3050F26B-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I could not find an answer to this issue anywhere else - I think that I have been able to create other object types in this factory - so, to get around this, I created the following bodge:

```
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection objTableArray = objDocument.getElementsByTagName("Table");
objTable = (mshtml.HTMLTable)objTableArray.item(0, 0);
```

Should I be able to do the regular create and there is a problem in my environment?

I do not like the bodge, so can anyone please suggest a proper alternative?

Kindest regards,

QuietLeni

Comment: Please clarify which .NET Framework you are using - your title says 3.5 but you tagged c#-4.0. Also it's not clear which component `mshtml.HTMLTable` is from i.e. which COM library you are referencing.

Comment: I am referencing the mshtml library (Microsoft HTML Object Library) Version 4.0.0.